# xsl:param default value is not being overridden

Tags: xslt

I have tried reducing my problem to as small a test case as possible.

I currently have the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="set-attrib">
      <xsl:param name="val" select="3"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
         <xsl:value-of select="$val" />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match='@value[parent::element]'>
      <xsl:call-template name="set-attrib">
         <with-param name="val">2</with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And applying it to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element value="0"/>
```

I get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element value="3"/>
```

rather than what I'd expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element value="2"/>
```

It appears that the template `set-attrib` is ignoring the parameter `val` that is being set in `call-template`.

I have dug around the net for ideas, and tried varied permutations (e.g. using `select="2"` in the `with-param`, or moving the default value of `xsl:param` into the `<!-- Content: template -->`, rather than in the `select` attribute) with no difference.

The only way I seem to be able to get it to work is by hard-coding the parameter within the `set-attrib` template or completely inlining the `call-template`.

I cannot see how this is different to other example code; am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<with-param name="val">2</with-param>` needs to be `<xsl:with-param name="val">2</with-param>`. With that change, http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BS works fine.